# How do I navigate from Algolia search results to the specific page?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, algolia

How do I navigate to the search results shown by Algolia?

Do I have to give each item (in this instance 15 different articles) a different key?

I can only figure out how to make it navigate to a specific article, and not an article based on which search result that got clicked on.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { connectInfiniteHits } from 'react-instantsearch-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const InfiniteHits = ({ hits, hasMore, refineNext, }) => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()


 return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={hits}
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={item => item.objectID}
        onEndReached={() => hasMore && refineNext()}
        renderItem={(({ item }, index) => (
            <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Articles',{item})}
            style={styles.item}>
              <View style={TextBoxes.scrollcontainer}>
              <View style={TextBoxes.boxes} key={index} >
                <Text key={index} style={TextBoxes.style} hit={item}>
                  {item.title}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
      />
    </View>
  )
};

InfiniteHits.propTypes = {
  hits: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
  hasMore: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  refineNext: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};


export default connectInfiniteHits(InfiniteHits);
```

Comment: As you can  `navigation.navigate('Articles',{item})`, Article screen can render dynamic article content depend on article user pressed.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Explore more - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: I tried going through the documentation, but my issue is: I have different kinds of articles, which doesn't all have the same property. So in my 'Articles' component i cant render a certain amount of jsx because of the variety within the Articles.

Comment: You can use React conditional rendering and render some JSX specific to certain articles - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/7-ways-to-implement-conditional-rendering-in-react-applications

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, the `item.objectID` of the article in your Algolia index record should be the unique ID needed by the `Articles` screen to retrieve and render the appropriate article.

If not, you may need to re-index with that value as the objectID or inject an additional attribute with the value you need to pass to the Articles screen for to render that article.

Comment: How would i approach should method in my Articles Screen? As of right now, my 'Articles' screen is a hardcoded article.